# Run the url and get the parameter value from result url-PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, I have created an url something like below:

```
https://example.com/as//authorization.oauth2?pfidpadapterid=ctct&client_id=1234567890&redirect_uri=https://localhost&response_type=code&scope=contact_data&
```

When I load that url, I got the `code` in the resulting url like:

```
https://localhost/?code=abcd-1111-0000-ffgh
```

And the parameter `code` : abcd-1111-0000-ffgh is my required result.

So I have the request url and have to retrieve code from response url. How can I do this using PHP?

Can I use CURL for this? I tried but the curl return the request url itself.

Below is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authURL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_exec($ch);
$new_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
curl_close($ch);
return $new_url;
```

So my aim is to create an url(already done), run that url and get the parameter from the result url programmatically using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You can get the URL parameters by using GET, for example

`www.example.com/user?id=1111&Fname=john&Lname=Doe`

...in your PHP : ...

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$Fname=$_GET['Fname'];
$Lname=$_GET['Lname'];
```

Comment: I know that.My question is not 'how to read parameters from url?', But `How to run a newly created url and get the parameters from the response url using PHP?`

Comment: Are you saying that this url `https://localhost/?code=abcd-1111-0000-ffgh`, has been created but not ran/loaded yet. And your question is how to run this created url first, right ?

Comment: No. I want to run the first long url (`https://example.com...`)  in my question. As a result `https://localhost/?code=abcd-1111-0000-ffgh` this will load and have to get the `code` parameter from that. I can done these manually. But need to do programatically using Curl or other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for what you are looking. This might help you

```
$context = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'max_redirects' => 5,
    ],
];

@file_get_contents('https://example.com/...//', null, stream_context_create($context));
echo '<pre>';print_r($http_response_header);die();
```

$http_response_header will be having location data